# g++ generates errors for an argument of transform()

Tags: c++, g++

g++ generates errors for this code. I have to change `std::sin` to `(double (*)(double))std::sin`. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::list<double> radians = {0.0, 3.14/2, 3.14};
    std::list<double> sines(radians.size());
    std::transform(radians.begin(), radians.end(), sines.begin(), std::sin);

    for(auto i = radians.begin(), j = sines.begin(); i != radians.end(); i++, j++)
        std::cout << "Angle and sine: " << *i << " " << *j << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::sin` is overloaded and the compiler can't figure out which overload to pass unless you cast it.

Comment: you don't want to use C cast for function pointers, it might not work for some implementations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) is function template, the type of function object parameter is declared as template parameter which needs to be deduced from the function argument. But [`std::sin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin) has several overloads, there's no context to determine which overload should be selected and then to be used to deduce the template argument.

You can use [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast#Notes) (or c-style cast as you showed) to specify one.

> `static_cast` may also be used to disambiguate function overloads by
>   performing a function-to-pointer conversion to specific type, as in
>
> ```
> std::for_each(files.begin(), files.end(),
>               static_cast<std::ostream&(*)(std::ostream&)>(std::flush));
> ```

e.g.

```
std::transform(radians.begin(), radians.end(), sines.begin(), static_cast<double(*)(double)>(std::sin));
```

Or specify the template argument explicitly to bypass the template argument deduction. With the known function parameter type overload resolution would be performed to select the proper overload.

```
std::transform<std::list<double>::iterator, 
               std::list<double>::iterator, 
               double(*)(double)
              >(radians.begin(), 
                radians.end(), 
                sines.begin(), 
                std::sin
               );
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your use case, another way to disambiguate the function overloads is to write a lambda accempting a specific type:

```
std::list<double> radians = {0.0, 3.14/2, 3.14};
std::list<double> sines;
std::transform(radians.begin(), radians.end(),
               std::back_inserter(sines),
               [] (double x) { return std::sin(x); });
//                 ^^^^^^
```

**Edit**

As noted by [walnut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11941443/walnut), since C++14, we can use `auto` and let the compiler deduce the value type from the iterators.

```
std::transform(radians.begin(), radians.end(),
               std::back_inserter(sines),
               [] (auto x) { return std::sin(x); });
```

Answer (score -1):

So writed.
You can use
     ...

```
 using namespace std;

 double sinn(double i){
     return sin(i);
 }
```

this function instead of sin.